# Crear id manualmente al dar de alta un registro

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trabajo con mysql 5.7 tengo la necesidad de dar de alta un registro pero crear el id al registrarlo.

Table: Prueba {idprueba int, not null, descripción varchar(100) not null}

mi sentencia es la siguiente

```
    INSERT INTO prueba (idprueba, descripcion)
VALUES ((SELECT COALESCE(MAX(idprueba), 0) + 1 FROM prueba), 'prueba1');
```

Tengo el siguiente mensaje: Código de error: 1093. No se puede especificar la tabla de destino 'prueba' para la actualización en la cláusula FROM

Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Hola. ¿Por qué no declaras `idprueba` como `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Haciendo eso se incrementará en cada inserción.

Comment: Así esta diseñada la tabla

Comment: ¿Y no es posible modificar esa tabla?

Comment: Iba a decir lo mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si `idprueba` debe ser autoincremental y no lo es, entonces ¡haz que sea autoincremental!.

El problema es que hacer otra cosa, aparte del enorme coste que podría tener a largo plazo, podría provocar gravísimos errores en los datos o en las eventuales relaciones, presentes o futuras, de esta tabla con otras tablas de la base de datos.

Y hay consecuencias también graves, como lentitud a la hora de consultar los datos, porque la columna no es lo que debería ser. Al declararla auto incremental, lo propio es declararla al mismo tiempo como llave primaria de la tabla.

Si no puedes crear / modificar tablas en esa base de datos por cuestiones de privilegios de acceso, entonces debes solicitar a alguien con privilegios superiores que normalice esa tabla.

Aquí te muestro una forma sencilla de normalizar esta situación. Lo primero, por si algo sale mal, es hacer una copia de la tabla y trabar sobre esa copia. Cuando veas que todo está bien, puedes borrar la tabla mal diseñada y renombrar la tabla normalizada dándole el nombre original.

> **MUY IMPORTANTE** si tu tabla está en producción (tiene datos) lo más recomendable es hacer un backup de la base de datos antes de todo este proceso, así, si algo sale mal, podrás restaurar todo a su estado original. Si por algún motivo no puedes hacer backup, de todos modos el proceso implica una copia de la tabla original que podrás guardar unos días hasta verificar que todo funciona con normalidad.

Te dejo un fiddle completo con todos los pasos y comentarios de lo que se va haciendo.

```
-- El CREATE TABLE original
CREATE TABLE `prueba` 
(
  `idprueba` INT NOT NULL, 
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

```
-- Insertamos unos datos de prueba
INSERT INTO `prueba` VALUES 
  (1,'A'),
  (4,'B'),  
  (7,'C'),
  (9,'D');
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- Verificamos los datos, con idprueba desordenado
SELECT * FROM `prueba`;
```

| idprueba | descripcion |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 7 | C |
| 9 | D |

```
-- Creamos una copia de prueba en tmp_prueba
-- Sólo la estructura, aún sin los datos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_prueba` LIKE `prueba`;
```

```
-- Verificamos estructura de nuestra tabla de trabajo
SHOW CREATE TABLE `tmp_prueba`;
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| tmp_prueba | CREATE TABLE `tmp_prueba` ( `idprueba` int(11) NOT NULL, `descripcion` varchar(100) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

```
-- Definimos la columna idprueba AUTO_INCREMENT y llave primaria
ALTER TABLE `tmp_prueba` 
  CHANGE `idprueba` `idprueba` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- Verificamos la nueva estructura de la tabla
SHOW CREATE TABLE tmp_prueba;
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| tmp_prueba | CREATE TABLE `tmp_prueba` ( `idprueba` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `descripcion` varchar(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`idprueba`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

```
/*
  Insertamos los datos en la nueva tabla
  Es importante tener en cuenta que aquí no ponemos
  la columna idprueba en la parte del INSERT
  ni tampoco en el SELECT
  porque esa columna queda bajo responsabilidad de SGBD
  será él quien la vaya incrementando.
  Sólo ponemos descripcion, y si la tabla tuviera más columnas
  debes ponerlas TODAS
*/
INSERT INTO tmp_prueba (descripcion)  
SELECT descripcion FROM `prueba`;
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- Verificamos los nuevos datos, ahora ordenados
SELECT * FROM `tmp_prueba`;
```

| idprueba | descripcion |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

```
/*
   Esto es para explicar el sentido lo que hacemos 
   en la consulta siguiente. Observa que el valor del 
   auto increment está en 8 y no en 5
*/
SELECT `auto_increment` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name = 'tmp_prueba';
```

| auto_increment |
| --- |
| 8 |

```
/*
   Esto parecerá extraño aquí, pero hay que hacerlo 
   para que el auto increment observe un conteo natural 
   luego del INSERT ... SELECT anterior.
   Y es que MySQL tiene un modo particular 
   de manejar el auto increment según los casos.
   Si quitas esto, el valor empezará de nuevo desde 8 u otro,
   como vimos en la consulta anterior.
   Para más detalles sobre este asunto ver:
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html
*/
ALTER TABLE tmp_prueba AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- Probamos que se corrigió el problema del auto increment
SELECT `auto_increment` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_name = 'tmp_prueba'
```

| auto_increment |
| --- |
| 5 |

```
-- Insertamos nuevos datos
INSERT INTO `tmp_prueba` (`descripcion`)  VALUES
('E'),
('F'),
('G');
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
-- Verificamos que los datos están ordenados
SELECT * FROM `tmp_prueba`;
```

| idprueba | descripcion |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |
| 7 | G |

```
/*
   Último paso: cuando verifiques que todo está correcto
   1. Renombra la tabla prueba con otro nombre
   2. Renombra la tabla temporal con el nombre original (prueba) 
   Puedes dejar la vieja tabla unos días por si acaso
   o guardarla en otro sitio durante un tiempo. 
   O, lo mejor de todo, haber hecho un backup 
   de la base de datos antes de todo este proceso
*/

-- Renombramos la tabla original
RENAME TABLE `prueba` TO `old_prueba`;

-- Renombramos la tabla temporal a la original
RENAME TABLE `tmp_prueba` TO `prueba`;
```

```
-- Verificamos consulta a la tabla con su nombre definitivo
SELECT * FROM `prueba`;
```

| idprueba | descripcion |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |
| 7 | G |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xlB_l4NZ)

Cuando veas que no necesitas a la tabla vieja, ejecuta esta instrucción para borrarla:

```
-- ADVERTENCIA: Instrucción peligrosa
-- No lo hagas si no sabes lo que estás haciendo

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `old_prueba`;
```

Comment: Comparto plenamente tus recomendaciones (va mi +1), pero el tema es que en la prácticas las cosas no siempre son como uno quiere, y la pregunta dice "manualmente" que sería justamente los contrario a usar "AUTO_INCREMENT"

Comment: @Yussef sí, pero observa que en la pregunta yo pregunté a OP por qué no usaba `AUTO_INCREMENT` a lo que él respondió: *Así está diseñada la tabla*. Entendí que era una limitación, por desconocimiento o por falta de privilegios de acceso o por otra causa. Por el motivo que sea, querer hacer un auto incremental *manualmente* no tiene ningún sentido, por todos los riesgos que ello supone. En este tipo de casos lo que hay que hacer es normalizar, o todo saltará por los aires de un momento a otro.